# Monitor strace in a loop, restart process when error string is matched

Tags: linux, bash, strace

I'm using a proprietary app on my Raspberry Pi 4.

The app has a bug where after a certain amount of time it slows to a crawl. It doesn't fully crash, it just starts performing sub-optimally. The fix is to kill the process and reopen it.

There is a flag in the apps console output I could use to determine that the problem has occurred: "Time taken to process image --249" (249 being the maximum it reports).

Is it possible to set up a .sh file to monitor strace for this process and then kill the process and re-open it? I've done plenty of Googling but I am out of my depth.

I would prefer not to write the strace to a text file and then read from that file. The console output from the application updates 60~ times per second and this would quickly ruin the SD card.

My instinct is to loop through the 10 most recent entries in the strace and look for a string match, but I can't figure our the syntax for that nor if it's even possible.

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) is very relevant here; note the process substitution use demonstrated therein. BTW, if you want a tool much faster/lower-overhead than strace, you might look at sysdig (though it requires root privileges, so may or may not be useful for your immediate scenario). Performance-wise, strace adds a _lot_ of overhead; it might end up taking the max reporting time _every_ time when monitoring with it!

Comment: (there are other low-overhead tracing tools available as well -- look into eBPF-based tracing; you also might be able to use a `LD_PRELOAD`ed library to hook into a library call made by your proprietary application and monitor what's going on that way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a fairly naive bash wrapper? Since you're using `strace` and we know it's well behaved when writing to a pipe (it will exit when the pipe stops reading) you should be able to just do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while strace -vF app 2>&1 | grep -q -m1 -- '--249'
do 
  echo restart 
  sleep X
done
```

Adjust the `X` in the `sleep` to a suitable value.

Personally I'd ask the maker of the proprietary app to sort their shit out ;)

Comment: What's the purpose of the command substitution? Granted, with `grep -q` there should be no stdout making it a noop, but that seems like a pretty obscure bit of syntax (that would misbehave if reused in even slightly different circumstances).

Comment: I would also suggest changing `|&` to `2>&1 |` to be teaching/demonstrating more widely compatible syntax, though that's more a matter of preference (albeit a preference shared by the authors of https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - I'll amend to those effects.

Comment: This looks great, but I’m testing it and the loop just immediately exists regardless of whether there should be a match?

Comment: BTW I adapted it for use against a process ID like so, which could be wrong: -vFp 818

Comment: Ah scratch that, I already had a strace session running. Seems to be working! I’ll give it a thorough test and then mark as the answer

Comment: Awesome - I'm glad to hear it does the trick! :)

Comment: @tink Really sorry to ask, but is there anyway we could change this to match any 3 digit number instead of 249? Unfortunately it's not as simple as I thought in my original question; it doesn't always end on 249, just any high number. I have tried '--[0-9][0-9][0-9]' and it's not picking it up.

Comment: @Psiloc This **should** work:  `grep -q -m1 -- '--[1-9][0-9][0-9]'` ... testing w/ `echo`ing without a loop gives the desired result ...

Comment: Yep got it working at about the same time :) the problem was that I hadn't configured all the strace arguments properly, I needed to do: `strace -vF -p app -s9999 -e write 2>&1` ... to get the console output. I'm not sure whether to edit your answer to include that because I didn't ever actually specify that requirement in my question.

Comment: Let's keep it generic, then  .. the more specific a problem, the less likely it's going to help others.